# Data recirculation between classes in C++ - error: '<class name>' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, header, declaration

I am preparing a program with several classes, which have to exchange data between each other subsequently in the code. This results in inclusion of classes in each other headers. I have encountered a problem when it came to passing a vector of "Gas" objects to the "Thermal" class method and afterwards trying to pass a changed "Thermal" object to the "Gas" class method. I have tried forward including of the classes in each other header files, but with a miserable result. Maybe I did something wrong with that. Possibly a declaration of a pointers between class objects would solve a problem? I have tired this, but unfortunately I may lack of experience with pointers, as I failed as well.

Notice - When I comment out the #include "Thermal.h" from the "Gas" class, the code compiles successfully. However, then the diffusion method has to be commented out as well.

The compilier returns, as follows:

```
./src/Thermal.h:86:76: error: template argument 2 is invalid
./src/solution.cpp: In function 'void solution(const Ref::Reformer&, 
const std::vector<Ref::Segment>&, std::ofstream*, std::ofstream*, std::ofstream*)':
./src/solution.cpp:92:40: error: no matching function for call to 'Ref::Thermal::
conduction(const Ref::Reformer&, Ref::Grid&, std::vector<Ref::Gas>&, Ref::Velocity&)'
  T.conduction(reactor, grid, gases, vel);
                                        ^
In file included from ./src/Gas.h:20:0,
                 from ./src/solution.cpp:16:
./src/Thermal.h:86:8: note: candidate: void Ref::Thermal::conduction(const Ref::Reformer&, 
const Ref::Grid&, const int&, const Ref::Velocity&)
   void conduction(const Reformer& RE, const Grid& GD, const std::vector<Gas>& GAS, 
const Velocity& VE);
        ^
./src/Thermal.h:86:8: note:   no known conversion for argument
 3 from 'std::vector<Ref::Gas>' to 'const int&'
```

Here is how I call the methods. Objects of class "Thermal" and "Gas" are created in the same .cpp file and are called subsequently. Their initialization requires construction and passing of a "Grid" class object, which is done in the same file as well.

Objects creation:

```
Grid grid(0.3, 0.052);
grid.setNX(90);
grid.setNR(15);

Thermal T(grid);
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){                                     
    gases.push_back(Gas(i, grid));
}
```

Methods' call:

```
 T.conduction(reactor, grid, gases, vel);
 for(int i = 0; i < gases.size(); i++){
     gases[i].diffusion(reactor, grid, vel, T);
 }
```

Grid class declaration:

```
#ifndef REFORMING_CODE_REF_GRID_H
#define REFORMING_CODE_REF_GRID_H

#include "../input.h"

namespace Ref{
    class Grid{
    public:
        Grid(const double& x1, const double& r1, const double& x0 = 0., const double& r0 = 0.){
            xmin_ = x0;
            xmax_ = x1;
            rmin_ = r0;
            rmax_ = r1;
        }

        void setNX(const int& nx){          //setting number of elements in the longitudinal direction 
            NX_ = nx;
            ni_ = NX_ - 1;
        }

        void setNR(const int& nr){          //setting number of elements in the radial direction
            NR_ = nr;
            nj_ = NR_ - 1;
        }
    };
}//end of namespace
#endif //REFORMING_CODE_REF_GRID_H
```

Thermal class declaration:

```
#ifndef REFORMING_CODE_REF_THERMAL_H
#define REFORMING_CODE_REF_THERMAL_H

#include "../input.h"
#include "Reformer.h"
#include "Grid.h"
#include "Velocity.h"
#include "Gas.h"

namespace Ref{
    class Thermal{
    public:
        Thermal(const Grid& grid){
            NX_ = grid.NX();
            NR_ = grid.NR();
        }

        void conduction(const Reformer& RE, const Grid& GD, const std::vector<Gas>& GAS, const Velocity& VE);


    private:
        int NX_;                                //quantity of elements in the X direction
        int NR_;                                //quantity of elements in the R direction

        std::vector<double> val_;               //Temperature value (K)
        std::vector<double> val_old_;
        std::vector<double> s_;                 //Thermal source
    };
} //end of namespace

#endif //REFORMING_CODE_REF_THERMAL_H
```

Conduction method definition:

```
#include "Thermal.h"
namespace Ref{ 
    void Thermal::conduction(const Reformer& RE, const Grid& GD, 
    const std::vector<Gas>& GAS, const Velocity& VE){}
}
```

Gas class declaration:

```
#ifndef REFORMING_CODE_REF_GAS_H
#define REFORMING_CODE_REF_GAS_H

#include "../input.h"
#include "Reformer.h"
#include "Grid.h"
#include "Velocity.h"
#include "Thermal.h"

namespace Ref{
    class Gas{
    public:
        Gas(const int id, const Grid& grid){
            id_ = id;
            NX_ = grid.NX();
            NR_ = grid.NR();
        }
        void diffusion(const Reformer&, const Grid&, const Velocity&, const Thermal&);
     private:
        int id_;                            
        int NX_;                            
        int NR_;                            
    };
} //end of namespace
#endif //REFORMING_CODE_REF_GAS_H
```

Diffusion method definition:

```
#include "Gas.h"

namespace Ref{
    void Gas::diffusion(const Reformer& RE, const Grid& GD, 
                         const Velocity& VE, const Thermal& T){}
} //end of namespace
```

Comment: You have circular includes. `Thermal.h` includes `Gas.h` while `Gas.h` includes `Thermal.h` It doesn't appear that you actually need all those includes - forward declarations should be sufficient.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will give it a try

Comment: Well, that have not solved the problem and generated even more errors. I have to include "Thermal.h" and "Gas.h" in the main file and when I include forward declarations in them, it results with redefinition error for the main file

Comment: You should have forward declarations in the .h files, and #includes in the .cpp files.

Comment: That is exactly how I changed it. Maybe I will try to experiment with that more.

Comment: Show the code you have now, and the exact and complete text of the error messages.

Comment: Just to clarify everything, you wanted me to move all includes to the .cpp files and add forward declarations in the .h files?
I did it in this manner (on Gas.h and Gas.cpp example) - I moved all the #include lines from Gas.h to Gas.cpp, as well all the methods that required using methods of the included classes. Then I added forward declarations to the Gas.h file, like this: 
namespace Ref{
class Reformer;
class Thermal; 
class Grid;
class Velocity;

class Gas{
public:
...
}; }//end of namespace

Answer (score 0):

You could try using forward declarations and moving the `#include` to the end of the header. ( your file wouldn't be included twice because of the header guards )

Minimal compiling example:

```
//RecursiveA.h

#ifndef RECURSIVEA_H
#define RECURSIVEA_H

class RecursiveA {
    public:
        void workOnB(const class RecursiveB &);
};

#include "RecursiveB.h"

#endif // RECURSIVEA_H

//RecursiveB.h

#ifndef RECURSIVEB_H
#define RECURSIVEB_H

class RecursiveB {
    public:
        void workOnA(const class RecursiveA &);
};

#include "RecursiveA.h"

#endif // RECURSIVEB_H

//RecursiveA.cpp
#include "RecursiveA.h"

void RecursiveA::workOnB(const RecursiveB &b){

}

//RecursiveB.cpp
#include "RecursiveB.h"

void RecursiveB::workOnA(const RecursiveA &a){

}
```